# How does postgres organize files

Tags: postgresql, file-organization

I read that we have various file organizations in DBMS(googled it) like sorted file organization, sequential file organization, heap file organization, etc.

How does a DBMS know which one to use? Does the developer specify it while creating the table? Or is it fixed for all tables in a DBMS?

I tried googling how i can set the file organization in postgres, but couldn't find any helpful resource. So, i started to wonder if each dbms has a fixed file organization

Comment: For Postgres, this is explained in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , i read it now. It says that the configuration of each cluster can be set. Does that mean each cluster has a fixed file organization, and that individual tables cannot have different file organizations?